# Recently deleted question does not appear in Meta "10k" tools

Tags: bug, meta, deleted-questions, 10k-tools

Last night, I marked [this meta question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/438/621) as a duplicate, and it was closed and deleted by the asker.  Unable to find the original link this morning, I went to the 10k Tools deleted section, but noticed no questions were listed.

[image: 10k Tools Recently Deleted Questions]

Is this a bug?

Note that I'm still tagging this with [10k-tools](/questions/tagged/10k-tools) as that is the slang name for the moderator tools awarded at 10,000 rep.  On Retrocomputing in Public Beta, these tools are awarded at [2,000 rep](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools).

Comment: It's not showing for me either. It might be because it was self-deleted.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 I thought any deleted questions show up in the 10k tools, not just ones where users that were not the OP voted to delete.  I wonder where this is documented...

Comment: Not a bug, it looks like [self-deleted answers are not visible in the 10k tools](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5864202#5864202).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a bug, [self-deleted answers are not visible in the 10k tools](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5864202#5864202) (thanks Shog).

I've opened a related question on Meta.SE: [Why are self-deleted posts not shown in the 10k Tools?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/292531/242209)